# How can I respond to mouse events in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d, mouse, flash-cs5

**Background:**

Trying to make a simple "drop the ball" game.

The code is located inside the first frame of the timeline. Nothing more is on the stage.

**Issue:**

Using QuickBox2D I made a simple If statement that drops and object acording the Mouse-x position:

```
if (MouseEvent.CLICK) {
sim.addCircle({x:mouseX, y:1, radius:0.25, density:5});
```

I imported the MouseEvent library:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
```

Nothing happens if I click, no output errors either.

**See it in action:**
http://gabrielmeono.com/download/Lucky_Hit_Alpha.swf
http://gabrielmeono.com/download/Lucky_Hit_Alpha.fla

**Full Code:**

```
    [SWF(width = 350, height = 600, frameRate = 60)]  
import com.actionsnippet.qbox.*;  
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var sim:QuickBox2D = new QuickBox2D(this);  
sim.createStageWalls();
//var ball:sim.addCircle({x:mouseX, y:1, radius:0.25, density:5}); //

// make a heavy circle 

sim.addCircle({x:3, y:1, radius:0.25, density:5});
sim.addCircle({x:2, y:1, radius:0.25, density:5});
sim.addCircle({x:4, y:1, radius:0.25, density:5});
sim.addCircle({x:5, y:1, radius:0.25, density:5});
sim.addCircle({x:6, y:1, radius:0.25, density:5});
// create a few platforms  

sim.addBox({x:3, y:2, width:4, height:0.2, density:0, angle:0.1});
// make 26 dominoes  
for (var i:int = 0; i<7; i++){  
//End
     sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:16, radius:0.1, density:0});
     sim.addCircle({x:2 + i * 1.5, y:15, radius:0.1, density:0});

//Mid end

      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:14, radius:0.1, density:0});
      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:13, radius:0.1, density:0});
      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:12, radius:0.1, density:0});
      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:11, radius:0.1, density:0});
      sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:10, radius:0.1, density:0});


      //Middle Start
     sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 1.5, y:09, radius:0.1, density:0});
     sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:08, radius:0.1, density:0});
     sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 1.5, y:07, radius:0.1, density:0});
     sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:06, radius:0.1, density:0});
} 

if (MouseEvent.CLICK) {
    sim.addCircle({x:mouseX, y:1, radius:0.25, density:5});

sim.start();  
/*sim.mouseDrag();*/  




    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't catch mouse-events like that.
You have to add an event listener, like this:

```
function handleClick(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    sim.addCircle({x:mouseX, y:1, radius:0.25, density:5});
}

addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
```